# I am trying to write a script to hide corresponding rows in pages in a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The function is triggered by a menu. when the user enters "Delivered" into the first page, I want that row to be hidden on most pages when the script is run. It hides them on the first page (active sheet) but not on the others.

I also need to keep the third page from changing (still showing all rows on that page)

Here is the link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I8HnORnogQ25E6jEHsNHIUpN6HiGWu9w6mm-CAnq4Ro/edit?usp=sharing

And the script I currently have is below.

```
function hideRows() {
  const obj = [{ sheetName: "testbed", checkCol: 11, checkValue: "DELIVER" }];
  hidetucan_(obj);
}

function showRowsInAllSheets_(sheets) {
  sheets.forEach(s => s.showRows(1,s.getMaxRows()));
}

function hidetucan_(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  showRowsInAllSheets_(sheets);
  const sheetObj = sheets.reduce((o,s) => (o[s.getSheetName()] = s, o), {});
  obj.forEach(({ sheetName, checkCol, checkValue }) => {
    const s = sheetObj[sheetName];
    if (s) {
      s.getRange(1, checkCol, s.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().forEach((e, i) => {
        if (e == checkValue) s.hideRows(i + 1, 1);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the task. So here is a guess:

```
function hide_rows_on_all_sheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("testbed")
  const colSdata = ws.getRange("K1:K" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();

  sheets.forEach(s => {
    for (let i = colSdata.length; i >= 0; i--) 
      if (colSdata[i] == 'DELIVER') s.hideRows(i+1);
  })
}
```

This function hides all the rows (on all the sheets) with the same indexes as the rows on sheet 'testbed' that contain 'DELIVER' in column K.

Results on the sheet 'testbed2':

[image]

As you can see rows 5, 8 and 12 are hidden. The same rows are hidden on the sheets 'testbed3' and 'testbed'.

**Update**

Here is the variant of the function that can skip some sheets:

```
function hide_rows_on_all_sheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("testbed")
  const colSdata = ws.getRange("K1:K" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const sheets_to_skip = ['testbed3', 'testbed4']; // <-------- here
  const sheets = ss.getSheets()
    .filter(s => !sheets_to_skip.includes(s.getName())); // <---- here

  sheets.forEach(s => {
    for (let i = colSdata.length; i >= 0; i--) 
      if (colSdata[i] == 'DELIVER') s.hideRows(i+1);
  })
}
```

You can add the names of sheets you want to skip into the array `sheets_to_skip`.

Comment: Correct, it is SUPPOSED to, but it only hides the rows on the testbed sheet and doesn't affect the others.

Comment: I just checked it again and it works fine with your sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wbrTKC19JBOiuP4liTZXCrq8gckop9Xda7I_ECUzWE0/edit?usp=sharing this function hides rows on all sheets. Try it

Comment: It works great! Thank you!!!    One other question, Is there a way to exclude some sheets from the script? For instance, I want testbed2 to change with testbed, but testbed 3 should remain unaltered...

Comment: Yes, it can be done pretty easy. See my update.